# Website Deployment method

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, compilation

I have a site which is live and I only have an FTP of that site so I just want to make some changes but I found that it is a compiled site and if I have to make any changes then I have to make modification and compiled it again and upload the file.

But when I check the `Bin` folder then I can see that there is only one `dll` file is created which is named as `mysite.com_deploy.dll` which is combined dll file.

So I don't know how this has been published or compiled?

Can anyone let me know about this?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit odd... if it has a DLL then it has been compiled, one dll for the whole site or one dll per page is a compile time option.

How you publish your site (how you move the compiled code to the web server) is another matter.

Which begs the question what is your real issue?

Try right clicking on the web deployment project -> properties and in the Output Assemblies : tick the option "Create a separate assembly for each page and control output" if you want multiple DLLs for one project. Taking this route can cause potential issues with naming of DLLs if you want to replace one.

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: How can I generate a single `dll` for the entire site ?

Comment: What happens when you compile the site? If you look in the BIN folder how many DLLs are in there? (not including 3rd party DLLs of course). Also is it a web project? if not what type of project is it?

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on the web deployment project -> properties and in the Output Assemblies : tick the option "Create a separate assembly for each page and control output" if you want multiple DLLs for one project. Taking this route can cause potential issues with naming of DLLs if you want to replace one.